# "this" inside a component's render function

Tags: reactjs, this

```
class GenreDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      genre: this.props.genres[0].genre
    }

    this.onGenreSelected = this.onGenreSelected.bind(this);
  }

  onGenreSelected(event) {
    console.log("genre selected!!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="genre-dropdown">
        {this.props.genres.map(function (genreUrlPair, idx) {
          return (
            <div
              className="genre-item"
              onClick={this.onGenreSelected} <== this is undefined!!
            >
              {genreUrlPair.genre}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Q1. I want `this` to refer to `GenreDropdown` component at the marked point. What did I do wrong?
Q2. Would you make a `GenreItem` component instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes an optional second argument that is used as `this` inside the function passed as the first argument. Pass `this`, which refers to the `GenreDropdown` instance at the time `map` is called:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className="genre-dropdown">
      {this.props.genres.map(function (genreUrlPair, idx) {
        return (
          <div
            className="genre-item"
            onClick={this.onGenreSelected}
          >
            {genreUrlPair.genre}
          </div>
        )
      }, this)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function created it's own context.

By using function(){}, this creates its own bindings.  So you could either use an arrow function

```
    {this.props.genres.map((genreUrlPair, idx) => {
      return (
        <div
          className="genre-item"
          onClick={this.onGenreSelected} <== this is undefined!!
        >
          {genreUrlPair.genre}
        </div>
      )
    })}
```

or bind the context yourself

```
    {this.props.genres.map(function (genreUrlPair, idx) {
      return (
        <div
          className="genre-item"
          onClick={this.onGenreSelected} <== this is undefined!!
        >
          {genreUrlPair.genre}
        </div>
      )
    }.bind(this))}
```